# Creating a semi-static default date field (fixed month and day, year=NOW)

Tags: datetime, forms

I have a date field that needs an unusual default date:  fixed day and month, but year=thisyear.  That's outside the standard default date options.

I didn't want to write a custom module for one form field, so I tried this in template.php

```
function secta_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'qic-node-form') {  // form to make a new QIC entry

  $QICdefault= date('Y')."-12-01";
  $form["field_qic_join"]["und"][0]['#default_value']['value'] = $QICdefault; // set the default  join date to YYYY-12-01

  }   // This is in template.php so will only show if form is displayed using the theme template 

}
```

But there is no sign of the form field default changing. :-(   What am I missing?

Comment: That form_alter array may not be right. IIRC, the syntax goes 
`$form["field_qic_join"]['#default_value'] = date('Y')."-12-01";`
Also, don't forget to clear caches.